# Reference cloud formation stacks in serverless components yaml

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless

Is there a way to import data from cloud formation stacks in same region, same as you would in a regular serverless.yml file when using serverless components? So import stuff using syntax like  `Fn::ImportValue`

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about importing a CloudFormation exported value directly into a serverless.yml file, then you can use the `${cf:XXX}` syntax. See https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-cloudformation-outputs